# Preserve URL even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 pages (A & B). When I go from A -> B, I have a form and a go back button. I want to know how to preserve A's URL, even after form is submitted or forms have error so that I can use back button to go to A .
I have tried `document.referrer`, `javascript.history.back()` and `localStorage`, but it seems to update the referrer URL.

Answer (score 0):

set **localStorage** when setting my state and then get the value from **localStorage** again inside of the **getInitialState** callback like:

```js
getInitialState: function() {
    var selectedOption = localStorage.getItem( 'SelectedOption' ) || 1;

    return {
        selectedOption: selectedOption
    };
},

setSelectedOption: function( option ) {
    localStorage.setItem( 'SelectedOption', option );
    this.setState( { selectedOption: option } );
}
```